# Ghanaian student flying from Turkey to Mexico

Tags: visas, turkey, mexico, ghanaian-citizens

I am an international student in Turkey and I have a Mexico tourist visa issued from my country, Ghana. Will it be a problem if I board from Turkey for a 13-day vacation?

Comment: How are you flying from Turkey to Mexico? Direct flight, or do you need to connect somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

> if i board from turkey for 13 days vacation

You can depart from anywhere with a visa to a country

Comment: Entry requirements may depend on the departing country.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Really? Can you name an example?

Comment: @lambshaanxy The only reason I see that happening is where most countries will mandate Yellow Fever vaccine if you were in a YF area in the last 14 days

Comment: @NicolasFormichella That's not going to be a concern when flying out of Turkey though.

Comment: @lambshaanxy the comment was on "You can depart from anywhere with a visa to a country".

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt That statement remains correct, even if there are other entry requirements (yellow fever vaccine, return flight, whatever).

Comment: @lambshaanxy Yes, my previous comment didn't question the answers' correctness (unlike some diseases such as covid).